# why doesn't my text-overflow property work?

Tags: css

I set the outside div to inline-block and set the width of it to 20px. When I set the text-overflow property to ellipsis, it doesn't work. Why is that? here is the picture:
[image]

Comment: add `overflow: hidden`, probably

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Use of `overflow:hidden`.

**2)** Use `white-space: nowrap;` for prevent from wrap text.

*and also,in your case:*

**3)** Use of `width:45px`. (Based on what I see on the picture,3 number is visible).

```css
div {
    width: 45px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>23132313</div>
```